# Sum a list in one line. Python

Tags: python, file, sum

I've tried to sum a list in one line, but without 'sum' function - without success. Is there any way to that?
One more thing, I also tried to find how many .txt files are in a folder in one line, but the best I did was in 2 lines. 
Can someone please explain me how to these two functions? (in one line each)
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt? That's not meant to sound _provocative_ or anything like that, but you'd benefit more (I think) from us showing you where you went wrong.

Comment: what do you wanna achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

Before `sum` existed, you could use `reduce`

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, somelist)
```

you can count the number of .txt files in one line like this:

```
print(len(__import__('glob').glob('*.txt')))
```